# how to interprete the descision tree result of sklearn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

1. Enviroment: 
   win10,python3,sklearn-0.18.2
2. problem description: 
   i used one variable 'province_area' to predit good or bad for an person. considering the variable 'province_area' is categorical features,so use 'DictVectorizer' 'fit_transform' to deal with it. but after generating the tree, there is a small red square in the label "'province_area=**'<=0.5".please click the link to get the graph. could you help tell me how to know the real value in the red square?

the code below

```
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()
dict_X_train = x.to_dict(orient='records')
x_train =vec.fit_transform(dict_X_train).toarray()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_train, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

import pydotplus
from IPython.display import Image  

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None,
                     feature_names=vec.get_feature_names(),  
                     filled=True, rounded=True, proportion=True,   
                     special_characters=False)  
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

[the decision tree graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgSQT.png)

Comment: That seems to be an issue in the font rendering. What are the column names in your data?

Comment: for x variable, only column names 'proince_area'  used.y=df3['f_m3'].values
x=df3.ix[:,['province_area']]

Comment: Can you post the result of `vec.get_feature_names()`?

Comment: the feature_names like this: ['province_area=NA', 'province_area=云南',
 'province_area=内蒙古', 'province_area=吉林',.......]

Comment: Yes, That maybe the reason. Those other language chars are not represented correctly in the graphviz image. Can you try with `feature_names=[name.decode('utf8') for name in vec.get_feature_names()]`?

Comment: thanks,it maybe the reason. but the code has error " 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' ".

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error on my Ubuntu. I used the values you specified in the province_area. Maybe your windows10 dont have the necessary fonts to display them properly.